# Sporadic Write Speed on USB Drobo Array

Tags: windows, hard-drive, drobo

I have a 2nd Gen Drobo (the 4-bay with USB 2 and FireWire 800) which is hooked up to a computer that acts as an office file server.  Lately I've noticed that it was seeming a bit slow, so I ran a bunch of tests to see if where the problem was.  I ran some speed tests over the network to another USB drive and those went through at around 35MB/s.  I then tested the drobo speed both on the server and another laptop and desktop.  On all, the speed is fairly consistent at around 14MB/s (and read of 19MB/s).  What worries me though is that the write speed graph is *all* over the chart.  On the image below, the top test is the Drobo (looks basically the same on all systems) and the bottom test is another USB hard drive that I had around.

As you can see, the regular USB drive (while not super fast, it was a 4800RMP portable, laptop size, drive) is nice and consistent.  The Drobo, however, is all over the place.  I can't imagine that thrashing about is good for performance.

Since it's on multiple computers, it's not a USB controller or anything.  So I worry the Drobo is going bad :(  Or maybe could it be fragmentation or something else that could be fixed?

Thanks!

**Edit**

Shane's comment got me thinking... and I remembered that a friend of mine has a first gen Drobo, so I ran a test on that.  Results below the first image, and yup, crazy all over the place on the write... maybe it IS just how Drobos are? But I would be remiss if I took that as empirical evidence of there not being a problem.  The other Drobo could also have a problem. Especially since it's 2 years older than mine :P

[image: DiskMark speed test]

[image: Friend's drobo (1st Gen)]

Comment: I'd be curious to see whether someone with another Drobo observes this same inconsistency.  It may just be a side-effect of the extra software abstraction handling RAID between the filesystem and disks.

Comment: @Shane - Definitely wondered the same thing.  Tried googling for a reference to that effect, but I guess I didn't hit on just the right keywords to get anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same unit and did a quick test of my own. On linux, and I used iozone, and O_DIRECT (minimize caching effects). My read/write numbers for sequential are eerily like yours. 14MB/s write, 26 MB/s read. Mine's on firewire 400.

```
File size set to 524288 KB
Record Size 64 KB
O_DIRECT feature enabled
Command line used: iozone -s 512M -r 64k -i 0 -i 1 -I
Output is in Kbytes/sec
Time Resolution = 0.000001 seconds.
Processor cache size set to 1024 Kbytes.
Processor cache line size set to 32 bytes.
File stride size set to 17 * record size.

          KB  reclen   write rewrite    read    reread
      524288      64   13485   15283    26090    27290
```

I do suspect some age related features are involved here, as it has been many months since I rebuilt the partitioning on it. I doubt the slowness can be remedied without a full rebuild, as the filesystem I ran the above test on is minimally consumed (5%) and highly unfragmented. As the above test is fully sequential, it's hard to get more ideal conditions then that.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time to run that.  Well, guess it's good to know that it's probably not just my unit.  And, actually mine has about 60% volume usage (though 0% fragmentation).  I did just look back at my tests though and noticed that while it still showed the jumpiness, on my much newer laptop, the average speed was about 15-20% faster.  Maybe it's just time for a new server... it is kinda old.

Comment: @AdamHaile Heh, the server I ran my test on is a hand-me-down and is about 10 years old (whoa! time passes!). So, not the newest either!

Comment: Ha, yeah... when I opened up my fileserver I noticed the year stamped on the motherboard read 2002! Time flies... didn't realize it was that old :P